# Is Apple's OpenCL implementation using CLang and LLVM open-source?

Tags: open-source, opencl, llvm

It's clear that Apple has an [OpenCL](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/OpenCLontheMacPlatform/OpenCLontheMacPlatform.html) implementation based on Clang and LLVM.  There's also a talk by an Apple Engineer about what it took to get OpenCL going on LLVM [here](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2009-10/)

However, is the code for this implementation available under some sort of open-source license or is this closed source software?  If the code hasn't been released, anyone know if perchance it might be in the future? Would like to know if there is an open-source OpenCL implementation based on Clang and LLVM before we go off and try to implement our own...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge(TTBOMK), the only (even partial) implementation of OpenCL that's open-source is [Clover](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/clover). Unfortunately, it's not finished or really even very close to usable, but you might want to look at it anyway.

Comment: TTBOMK?  What does that mean?

Comment: TTBOMK = To the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @gbrandt: it can be interpreted either of two ways: either as "To The Best Of My Knowledge", or as "Good God, this dinosaur must have been posting when 'the backbone' ran on 9600 bps modems." Come to think of it, they're not mutually exclusive either...

Comment: Ok, fixed the answer so that it is understandable. (expanded acronym)  :-)  By your definition, I'm a dinosaur and I did not know that!  Maybe not a smart dinosaur.

Comment: pocl (http://pocl.sourceforge.net/) is another open-source implementation of OpenCL

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe the hard parts are all in clang. For instance, it's ext_vector_type extension is basically what you get in OpenCL. I don't think any of Apple's host part is open. The hard compiler part I would think is all there for you in clang.